# Variable is true but images are not turning to Gifs - Class / ElementID

Tags: javascript, class, variables, constructor, getelementbyid

I am trying to turn an image to a gif instead when GifsActive is true which it is when someone ticks the box.

I have tried to create functions in the class and outside and call them, but this doesn't seem to work, I've created this.gif = gifs and tried to call a function to set it from false to true but it still doesn't work.

```
class Queen {

   constructor(name, acting, comedy, dance, design, improv, runway, lipsync, image = "noimage", custom = false, guestjudge = false, country = "none", gifs = false) {
      this.trackRecord = [];
      this.friends = [];
      this.enemies = [];
      this.sisters = [];
      this.miniEpisode = [];
      this.tCaptain = [];
      this.voteHerstory = [];
      this.immuneEp = [];
      this.runwayScore = 0;
      this.lipsyncScore = 0;
      this.performanceScore = 0;
      this.finaleScore = 0;
      this.favoritism = 0;
      this.unfavoritism = 0;
      this.ppe = 0;
      this.stars = 0;
      this.episodesOn = 0;
      this.votes = 0;
      this.rankP = 0;
      this.retEp = 0;
      this.blocked = false;
      this.QueenDisqOrDept = false;
      this.customqueen = false;
      this.immune = false;
      this.chocolate = false;
      this.maxiT = false;
      this._name = name;
      this._actingStat = acting;
      this._comedyStat = comedy;
      this._danceStat = dance;
      this._designStat = design;
      this._improvStat = improv;
      this._runwayStat = runway;
      this._lipsyncStat = lipsync;

      if (image == "noimage")
         this.image = "image/queens/noimage.jpg";
      else if (custom == true)
         this.image = image;
      else if (guestjudge == true)
         this.image = "image/judges/" + image + ".webp";
      else if (gifsActive == true)
         this.image = "image/judges/" + image + ".gif";
      else
         this.image = "image/queens/" + image + ".webp";

      if (country == "none")
         this.country = "image/country/noimage.jpg";
         
      else if (country == "UK")
         this.country = "image/country/UK.png";

      else if (country == "USA")
         this.country = "image/country/USA.png";

      else if (country == "SWEDEN")
         this.country = "image/country/SWEDEN.png";

      else if (country == "CAN")
         this.country = "image/country/CAN.png";

      else if (country == "THAI")
         this.country = "image/country/THAI.png";

      else if (country == "BELGIUM")
         this.country = "image/country/BELGIUM.png";

      else if (country == "DU")
         this.country = "image/country/DU.png";

      else if (country == "SPAIN")
         this.country = "image/country/SPAIN.png";

      else if (country == "FRANCE")
         this.country = "image/country/FRANCE.png";

         else if (country == "DEN")
         this.country = "image/country/DEN.png";

      else if (country == "AUS")
         this.country = "image/country/AUS.png";

      else if (country == "INDIA")
         this.country = "image/country/INDIA.png";

      else if (country == "BRAZIL")
         this.country = "image/country/BRAZIL.png";

      else if (country == "ISRAEL")
         this.country = "image/country/ISRAEL.png";

      else if (country == "PHIL")
         this.country = "image/country/PHIL.png";

      else if (country == "CHINA")
         this.country = "image/country/CHINA.png";

      else if (country == "HOL")
         this.country = "image/country/HOL.png";

      else if (country == "ITALY")
         this.country = "image/country/ITALY.png";

      else
         this.country = "image/queens/" + country + ".png";
   }

   _calculateScores(min, max, stat = 0) {
      let score = randomNumber(min, max);
      return score - stat;
   }
   getName() {
      return this._name;
   }
   getLipSyncStat() {
      return this._lipsyncStat;
   }
   getActing() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, this._actingStat);
   }
   getComedy() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, this._comedyStat);
   }
   getMarketing() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(25, 45, this._comedyStat + this._actingStat);
   }
   getDance() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, this._danceStat);
   }
   getDesign() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, this._designStat);
   }
   getRunwayChallenge() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, this._runwayStat);
   }
   getImprov() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, this._improvStat);
   }
   //special 'gets':
   getSnatch() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(25, 45, this._improvStat + this._comedyStat);
   }
   getRusical() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(25, 45, this._danceStat + this._lipsyncStat);
   }
   getBall() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(25, 45, this._designStat + this._runwayStat);
   }
   getRumix() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(25, 45, this._danceStat + this._improvStat);
   }
   getTalentShow() {
      this.performanceScore = this._calculateScores(15, 35, randomNumber(1, 35));
   }
   getFinale() {
      this.finaleScore = this.favoritism - this.unfavoritism;
   }
   getRunway() {
      this.runwayScore = this._calculateScores(12, 35, this._runwayStat);
   }
   getLipsync() {
      this.lipsyncScore = this._calculateScores(0, this._lipsyncStat, this.unfavoritism) + this.favoritism;
   }
   getASLipsync() {
      this.lipsyncScore = this._calculateScores(0, this._lipsyncStat);
   }
   addToTrackRecord(placement) {
      this.trackRecord.push(placement);
   }
   editTrackRecord(added) {
      this.trackRecord[this.trackRecord.length - 1] += added;
   } 
}
```

Button you check to turn the variable true

```
let gifsActive = false;

if (document.getElementById("gifMode").checked == true) {
      gifsActive = true;
   }
```

gifMode is in the HTML as a checkbox and it is spelt correctly.

here is the person I'm trying to change to a gif

```
let sashaColby = new Queen("Sasha Colby", 12, 9, 13, 10, 8, 14, 14, "SashaColby", false, false,"USA", false);
```

The second string "" is the image as a WEBP, but I also have a GIF format one as the same name in the same folder to ensure that when it switches, it should only change the format.

HTML ---

```
<input class="optleft" type="checkbox" id="gifMode"> Enable Gifs
```

ANY HELP is appreciated, I've been trying for hours but no matter what I do, it just won't work.

Comment: "*I am trying to turn an image to a gif instead when GifsActive is true which it is when someone ticks the box.*" <<--- ?? What?

Comment: @mykaf I've added the HTML - the checkbox is checked on the website and the rest of my checkboxes work fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've got 2 images in my folder, 1 is a WEBP and 1 is a GIF. I want to change the format from WEBP to GIF to select the GIF when the checkbox is ticked for gifs.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what the code you've posted has to do with the question you are asking. If you have multiple file formats available and simply want a way to display one format upon a checkbox selection, just use CSS to show/hide the appropriate file type.

Comment: Also, although it is legal to omit curly braces around the branching code of it/else statements, that is only for when there is one statement to perform in that branch. Omitting the braces opens the door to bugs down the line if you add a second statement but forget to add the braces. So, as a best practice, you should always put your branching code within curly braces.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am trying to change the artists image from WEBP to GIF when the gifActive box is checked, I will definitely use curly braces for the branching if statements for future ref :)

 I'm confused on what you mean by just use CSS to show/hide the appropriate file type. I have other images on the website, I only want it to affect the person above only.

Comment: Why can't you just (upon the checking of the checkbox), gather up the appropriate `img` elements from the DOM and change their `src` attribute so that it has the correct file extension, based on the checkbox state? As long as the file name portion and location of the webp and gif images is the same, adjusting the src would do it. Simple. I don't understand how just about all the code you've posted is relevant to this operation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I can't do that because there is over 200 different people, I use another class to create an image and the image element = image.src = source. Source is the person's string text on their variable.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the image src dom element to display the gifs instead of webp with .replaceALL and it now works!!

Thank you for all the help!